# How to change all highlighted rows in DataGridView - VB.NEt

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Begginer's question. I'm trying to write small piece of code in Visual Studio (VB.net) that will change value of a particular field of the database for all highlightetd rows. So, I'm running my form, which displays some data from the datatabse. I then highlight some rows (holding Ctrl and clicking). Next I click a button that will trigger a value change for all the highlighted rows (only). Say, I want to change the "Name" column's value for all of them.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!
Damo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGridView.SelectedRows property contains a collection of all of the rows that the user has selected.  You can spin through this collection and do what you wish with each row.

See [this article](http://www.automatedqa.com/community/Home/Articles/tabid/38/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/517/Default.aspx) for more information and example code.